# python - logging: How to access handler from config file

Tags: python, django, python-logging

I am trying to use logging in Django Application. I want to predifine my formatters and handlers in config file and later use different handlers at different times as per the need.

Currently i am using the following logger config in my settings.py

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'format1': {
            'format': '[%(duration).3f] %(statement)s',
        },
        'format2': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s %(funcName)s() %(pathname)s[:%(lineno)s] %(name)s \n%(message)s'
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'console1': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'formatter': 'format1',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        },
        'console2': {
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'format2',
            'level': 'DEBUG',
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way i can use the handlers specified in the settings.py file

like:

```
import logging
def someview(request)
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    logger.addHandler("name of the handler from confi file i.e console1 or console2")
    #I tried 
    # logger.addHandler('console1') it says 
    #  Attribute Error - 'str' object has no attribute 'level'
    #  if record.levelno >= hdlr.level:
    #  /usr/lib64/python3.7/logging/__init__.py in callHandlers, line 1590
    #
```

So how to use the handler mentioned in the config file

Comment: `addHandler` takes a `Handler` instance, so you'd need to initialise one yourself, e.g. `StreamHandler()`

Comment: You could create the different loggers you want in your settings file and then pull them in your app by logger name when you need the differing style: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/logging/#naming-loggers

Comment: @Nick defining logger name is one solution. But i prefer to use the logger name as "__name__"

Comment: @dirkgroten. Mainly the formatter will vary. So its not possible to utilize the handlers from config files